# Google Calendar: Remove yourself from an event you were invited to

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar

I've been invited to a calendar event and accepted it. The event is set to repeat indefinitely. I want to end my invitation after a certain set date.

If I change the end date from the event settings, will it change the main event settings as well, or only my instance?

I also looked into using the `Google-Apps-Script` to delete all future events from my calendar instance but it only works for set date range and cannot delete indefinite future events.

Comment: Did you create the event?

Comment: @Tedinoz No I did not.

Comment: How are you progressing with your problem? Did you solve it, or are you still looking for help?

Comment: @Tedinoz I was not able to find a solution to this problem. What I ended up doing was deleting the event occurrences from my calendar for a set amount of time (one year), but wasn't able to remove all. This ended up generating an absurd amount of calendar notifications being sent to the owner of the event.